# SQL Server 2008 OPENROWSET permission issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 64-bit Enterprise on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise 64-bit. I find when I execute the following statement in SQL Server Management Studio, I need sysadmin permission. I am using the statement to import data from Excel to a database table. My question is, I am concerned that sysadmin permission is too high, any solutions to use lower privileged permission to implement the same function?

```
select * from  OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\mytest1.xlsx',sheet1$)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From books online [OPENROWSET (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

The user requires the `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` permission.

And [here is the entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx) for GRANTing it.  It is a server-level permission, so yes, it is quite high.

To try lower permissions, you could create a standard linked server connection and add a login using

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'LINKSERVERNAME', 'false',
    'localuser', 'rmtuser', 'rmtpass'
```

There does not appear to be any specific permissions required to be granted, so if you set up a linked server, it is unwise to set it up with a generic `linkedsrvlogin` that maps to every local user.  Set up specific local-remote mappings to control the access of a local user, through the linked-server, at the remote server (by the `rmtuser` login).

Comment: Thanks, I am interested in the linked server solution. Using linked server, what is the lowest permission needed? Could you refer me a guide or tutotial?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from  OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\mytest1.xlsx',sheet1$)
```

Please try with this one