# OpenRowSet and OpenDataSet without sysadmin rights

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to use the OpenRowSet and OpenDataSet commands in SQL Server 2008 R2 without having to have SysAdmin rights?

I'm trying to load data from an Excel file and our service account that will do the actual loading can't have sysadmin rights.

It's currently not a linked "server" and the file name can change from month to month.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  
  Center,
  Amount 
FROM OPENROWSET(
  'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
  ,'Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;Database=C:\exceldata.xls'
  ,'SELECT 
      F1 as Center,
      F2 as Amount
   FROM [Sheet1$]')
WHERE Amount > 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily require sysadmin rights, just the `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` permission (which is a server level permission but not quite sysadmin).

If this isn't an option, you can try setting up a linked server connection and follow the method in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777906/sql-server-2008-openrowset-permission-issue).

Comment: Is there some other security setting that's needed?  My user has ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS permission but I still get the error:
Msg 7415, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' has been denied. You must access this provider through a linked server.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem and solve it with this instructions http://www.johnsoer.com/blog/?p=538

Shortly: add dword register key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\YOUR_MSSQL_VERSION.YOR_INSTANCE_NAME\Providers\Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0\DisallowAdhocAccess to 0

Comment: Adhoc queries are not allowed so this won't work.  I found a workable solution though, we added the ACE drivers and then converted the Excel file to a CSV file programattically.