# SQL Server cannot execute 'Microsoft.Ace.OleDB.12.0'

Tags: sql-server

I've removed the sysadmin role from a certain user but now I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 7415, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
>   Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' has been denied. You must access this provider through a linked server.

when performing the following query:

```
Select * 
from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
                ,    'Excel 12.0;Database=F:\Folder\Foo.xls;HDR=YES'
                , 'SELECT * FROM [bar$]')
```

What should I set to user "MyUser" in order to fix this problem? Assigning "sysadmin" is not option anymore.

Comment: Have you enabled the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using `sp_configure`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenRowSet and OpenDataSet without sysadmin rights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943370/openrowset-and-opendataset-without-sysadmin-rights)

Comment: I've changed to indeed, did not solve the issue.
ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS did not work either.